# Is Ruby on Rails less secure than Java EE or asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jakarta-ee

We develop HR-software for large companies. We primarily use Ruby on Rails for our projects. The argument I often get from clients is that RoR is less secure than, say, Java EE or asp.net because it is community-driven and it is not backed by large corporations as Oracle or Microsoft.

Is it a valid argument? Could you tell what technology is less / more secure statistic-wise?

Comment: I think those are not valid reasons to determine "security". May be what they meant was "support".

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nambari! What they mean is that Microsoft (in case of asp.net) has everything under control, while RoR-community has lots of trouble organizing their collaboration.

Comment: "everything under control" may cause issues too. For example, Oracle and Google dispute on Java/Android. Anyway I feel there is no specific answer for this question rather than your company backing up saying "we have RoR experts to support (if community is not there).

Comment: That's like saying linux isn't as secure as windows because it doesn't have one large company taking responsibility.  I hardly think the internet would run on linux if it wasn't secure.  I'm not saying compare rails to linux in terms of security, though.  I'm just saying the argument is not valid.